# R identifying new user IDS based on date

Tags: r, loops, date, tapply

I have a dataset of 2 years of user text messages - 2015 and 2016 (135,000). I am trying to identify new users to this program for February 2016 (based on subscriber_id and entity=="subscribe-online").

The wrinkle is that a new user is one where the subscriber_id has not occurred in the data within the past 12 months. So, for example, if I have the following sample data:

```
created              subscriber_id   cellnum   entity          message  msgtxt
2015-21-01 14:03:00   15855        7788826943   tip             100     end
2015-07-12 14:03:00   15839        7788815940   tip             24      tip 24
2015-08-12 14:03:00   15839        7788815940   stop            99      stop
2016-01-01 14:05:00   15800        2508816941   tip             25      tip 25 
2016-02-01 16:05:00   15800        2508816941   tip             26      tip 26 
2016-03-01 14:05:00   15800        2508816941   tip             27      tip 27 
2016-01-02 14:03:00   15855        7788826943  subscribe-online  1      msg 1
2016-01-02 14:03:00   15839        7788815940  subscribe-online  1      msg 1
```

15855 and 15839 both subscribe on February 1. I want to be able to assign 15855 as a new user based on the fact that the last occurrence of the subscriber_id 15855 was on Jan 21, 2015 - more than 12 months. I would like to assign 15839 as a repeat user since their last occurrence was on December 8th, 2015 (less than 12 months).

The created (date) field is in POSIXct, format. I have been trying to understand loops and sapply and tapply to see how I could use this here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(created = c("2015-21-01 14:03:00","2015-12-07 14:03:00","2015-12-08 14:03:00","2016-01-01 14:05:00","2016-02-01 16:05:00","2016-03-01 14:05:00","2016-01-02 14:03:00","2016-01-02 14:03:00"),
                 subscriber_id = c(15855,15839,15839,15800,15800,15800,15855,15839),
                 cellnum = c(7788826943,7788815940,7788815940,2508816941,2508816941,2508816941,7788826943,7788815940),
                 entity = c("tip","tip","stop","tip","tip","tip","subscribe-online","subscribe-online"),
                 message = c("100","24","99","25","26","27","1","1"),
                 msgtxt = c("end","tip 24","stop","tip 25 ","tip 26 ","tip 27 ","msg 1","msg 1"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                )

df$created <- as.POSIXct(df$created, format = "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")


df <- df %>%
      arrange(subscriber_id, created) %>%
      group_by(subscriber_id) %>%
      mutate(new_user = if_else(entity != "subscribe-online", NA, if_else(as.numeric(difftime(created, lag(created), units = "days") > 365) == TRUE, TRUE, NA)))
```